# Does WriteAllLines delete the existing file and recreate it, or overwrite the data inside it?

Tags: vb.net, save, streamwriter, overwrite, txt

I use the `File.WriteAllLines()` method in my project. The txt file is to be synced to a remote server (via another application, Autodesk Docs in my case) upon Save action.

I am not sure why, but using `WriteAllLines` does not trigger syncing of the file, while opening it and performing a save manually does trigger the sync.

I suspect it's maybe due to `WriteAllLines` deleting the existing file and creating a new one instead of overwriting the data inside the file...?
Is there a way to overwrite by deleting the existing the data in the file instead of deleting the existing file and creating a new file?

Am I even right about `WriteAllLines` deleting the existing file and recreating it?

Comment: I don't know if it'll work, but you could try using [`FileStream.SetLength`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.setlength) to set the length of the file to zero and then write the data to that stream. `Using fs = New FileStream("C:\temp\aab.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate)` `fs.SetLength(0)` `Using sw = New StreamWriter(fs)` `'write text...` etc.

Comment: You can investigate what happens to the file by using [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) with suitable filters.

Comment: You can test your theory with `File.WriteAllLines("temp.txt", Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Select(Function(c) c.ToString()))` repeatedly and see that the creation date will remain the same while the modification date is changed. The file is not deleted

Comment: You can also try different methods: 
`Using sw As New StreamWriter(filename, False)`, 
`Using fs As New FileStream(filename, FileMode.Truncate) Using sw As New StreamWriter(fs)`, 
`Using sw As New StreamWriter(filename, True)`, 
`Using fs As New FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create) Using sw As New StreamWriter(fs)`